# Filtro em pesquisa sem exibir tabela ao carregar a página

Tags: angularjs

Olá. Estou com uma dúvida em relação aos filtros. Eu gostaria de um filtro semelhante ao do código abaixo, porém sem exibir a tabela com todos os valores ao carregar a página pela primeira vez.

Somente após a pesquisa é que apareciam os valores já filtrados. Como seria?

```
   <div id="notebooks" ng-app="notebooks" ng- 
   controller="NotebookListCtrl">
   <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query"/>
   <select ng-model="orderList">
   <option value="name">By name</option>
   <option value="-age">Newest</option>
   <option value="age">Oldest</option>
   </select>
   <ul id="notebook_ul">
   <li ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | filter:query | orderBy: orderList">
  name: {{notebook.name}}<br/>
  procesor: {{notebook.procesor}}<br/>
  <div class="right top">{{notebook.age}}</div>
  </li>
  </ul>
    <span>Number of notebooks: {{notebooks.length}}</span>
    </div>
```

Código completo aqui:
https://codepen.io/bartaxyz/pen/nCfAj

Comment: De onde você vai buscar esses dados?

Comment: De um Json no controller. No link que eu coloquei ali em baixo tem o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consigo pensar em duas maneiras.
A primeira e mais fácil é adicionar um botão de busca. O usuário preenche o campo de busca clica no botão que executa uma função que faz a busca, filtra e preenche o `$scope.notebooks`

Ai é só remover `| filter:query`

Fica algo assim:

```
<div id="notebooks" ng-app="notebooks" ng- controller="NotebookListCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query" />
  <button ng-click="search()">Buscar</button>
  <select ng-model="orderList">
    <option value="name">By name</option>
    <option value="-age">Newest</option>
    <option value="age">Oldest</option>
  </select>
  <ul id="notebook_ul">
    <li ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | orderBy: orderList">
      name: {{notebook.name}}<br />
      procesor: {{notebook.procesor}}<br />
      <div class="right top">{{notebook.age}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>Number of notebooks: {{notebooks.length}}</span>
</div>

<script>
  $scope.notebooks = []

  $scope.search = function () {
    /* 
    Voce pode buscar tudo no servidor e usar o filter com $scope.query para filtrar o resultado ou fazer a busca com o query
     */
    $scope.notebooks = result // coloca o resultado no notebooks
  }
</script>
```

A outra forma é usar o [ngKeyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) e ir buscando a medida que o usuário for digitando.
Você criar uma função que faz a busca usando o `$scope.query` e adiciona `ng-keyup="onSearch()"` no input de busca

Fica algo assim:

```
<div id="notebooks" ng-app="notebooks" ng- controller="NotebookListCtrl">
  <input type="text" id="query" ng-model="query" ng-keyup="onSearch()" />
  <select ng-model="orderList">
    <option value="name">By name</option>
    <option value="-age">Newest</option>
    <option value="age">Oldest</option>
  </select>
  <ul id="notebook_ul">
    <li ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | orderBy: orderList">
      name: {{notebook.name}}<br />
      procesor: {{notebook.procesor}}<br />
      <div class="right top">{{notebook.age}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>Number of notebooks: {{notebooks.length}}</span>
</div>

<script>
  $scope.notebooks = []
  $scope.onSearch = function () {
    // Procura as informaçoes baseadas em $scope.query
    /* Voce pode buscar tudo no servidor e usar o filter com $scope.query para filtrar o resultado ou fazer a busca com o query
     */
    $scope.notebooks = result // coloca o resultado no notebooks
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Fiquei com a segunda opção. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada! Não esquece de aprovar a resposta( sinal de check próximo a seta pra baixo)  ;)